# Should I be able to understand this ContentPlaceHolder behavior?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, contentplaceholder

My goal is to be able to define a class for the  element in a child page. On my master page I have the following:

```
<body class="<myown:AttributePlaceHolder runat="server" ID="BodyCssClass"/>">
```

The `AttributePlaceHolder` derives from `ContentPlaceHolder`, and just strips out any linebreaks and extra spaces from its content. The problem I will describe also occurs when changing the `AttributePlaceHolder` into a normal `ContentPlaceHolder` .

Now the above stated piece of code doesn't work, and will end up in the following error:

> Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder
>   'BodyCssClass' in the master page
>   '/Views/Shared/Site.Master', verify
>   content control's ContentPlaceHolderID
>   attribute in the content page

When changing the above line of code into:

```
<body class="<% %><myown:AttributePlaceHolder runat="server" ID="BodyCssClass"/>">
```

It does work (note the added `<% %>`).

It does the trick, just wondering if I'm missing something here.

Just for the extra info, in my child pages I can write:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyCssClass" runat="server">profile-edit someotherclass another-class</asp:Content>
```

or even:

```
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyCssClass" runat="server">profile-edit
someotherclass

another-class
</asp:Content>
```

and it will be nicely printed out as:

```
<body class="profile-edit someotherclass another-class">
```

**Edit**
As pointed out by Johan the following also works:

```
<body class='<myown:AttributePlaceHolder runat="server" ID="BodyCssClass"/>'>
```

Changes the double quotation marks into single ones.

But than my html would also show up with single quotation marks. Call me crazy, but that just hurts me...

I guess it has to do with the ASP.NET parsing engine, in that case should we call it a bug, or a "feature"?

Comment: Couldn't you just change where the single quotation marks are?

<body class="<content runat='server' />">

Comment: That should indeed work. That is one of those thing you go "dohhh". 
Anyway still doesn't explain the behaviour.

Comment: No, at once it doesn' really make any sense, but if you think about it; when has double quotes inside another pair of double quotes ever worked without escaping or changing them to singe quotes? So in a way it makes sense, yet in a another way it doesn't..

Comment: But that would explain the behavior of adding <%%> to it to make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also achieve the double quotation marks in the output without using the server tags by reversing the quotes setup:

`<body class="<myown:AttributePlaceHolder runat='server' ID='BodyCssClass'/>">`

The runat and ID attributes of the place holder are single quoted. As to why the server tag makes the original code work, only the demons inside the parsing engine know that...

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
<body class='<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat="server">ms-areaseparator</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>' ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about this?

In your aspx page have set the body tag to be a server object

```
<body runat="server" id="HtmlBody">
```

Then in your code behind you can set any attributes you like

```
HtmlBody.Attributes.Add("class", "your-css-class-name");
```

Which produces the following markup

```
<body id="ctl00_HtmlBody" class="your-css-class-name">
```

Comment: Although I did not state it in the text, I did tag it as MVC. So I don't have code behind, and don't want to set the class name in the controller. The class name should be set in the view.